# Remove data from a SQLite database inside a RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I want to remove the data from mydatabase inside my RecyclerAdapter.

I've also got a swipe class that deletes the items from the RecyclerView.
Now, I'm able to remove the items from the RecyclerView, but not from the database as my database can't be called on the RecyclerAdapter.

This is my ManagerActivity.

```
public class Manager2 extends AppCompatActivity  {
    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    RecyclerView recycler;
    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manager2);
        initializeViews();

        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new Swipe(adapter);
        ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler);
    }

    public void initializeViews(){
        List<Password> myPasswords = db.getAllPasswords();
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myPasswords);
        recycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    }
}
```

SQLite Database class

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Passwords table name
    public static final String TABLE_BOOKS = "passwords";

    // Passwords Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    public static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_TITLE,KEY_PASSWORD};

    // Database Version
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PasswordDB";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SQL statement to create password table
        String CREATE_PASSWORD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE passwords ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "title TEXT, "+
                "password TEXT )";

        // create books table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PASSWORD_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older passwords table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS passwords");
        // create fresh passwords table
        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addPassword(Password password){
        //for logging
        Log.d("addBook", password.toString());

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, password.getTitle()); // get title
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password.getPassword()); // get password

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_BOOKS, // table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

        // 4. close
        db.close();
    }

    public Password getPassword(int id){

        // 1. get reference to readable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        // 2. build query
        Cursor cursor =
                db.query(TABLE_BOOKS, // a. table
                        COLUMNS, // b. column names
                        " id = ?", // c. selections
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                        null, // e. group by
                        null, // f. having
                        null, // g. order by
                        null); // h. limit

        // 3. if we got results get the first one
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        // 4. build password object
        Password password = new Password();
        password.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        password.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
        password.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));

        //log
        Log.d("getPassword("+id+")", password.toString());

        // 5. return book
        return password;
    }


    public List<Password> getAllPasswords() {
        List<Password> passwords = new LinkedList<Password>();

        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BOOKS;

        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
        Password password = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                password = new Password();
                password.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                password.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                password.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));

                // Add password to passwords
                passwords.add(password);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Log.d("getAllPasswords()", passwords.toString());

        // return passwords
        return passwords;
    }

    public int updatePassword(Password password) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, password.getTitle()); // get title
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password.getPassword()); // get password

        // 3. updating row
        int i = db.update(TABLE_BOOKS, //table
                values, // column/value
                KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(password.getId()) }); //selection args

        // 4. close
        db.close();

        return i;
    }

    public boolean updatePass(int id, String title, String password ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID,id);
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,title);// get title
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password); // get password
        db.update(TABLE_BOOKS,values,"id = ?",new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
        return true;
    }

    public void deletePassword(Password password) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. delete
        db.delete(TABLE_BOOKS, //table name
                KEY_ID+" = ?",  // selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(password.getId()) }); //selections args

        // 3. close
        db.close();

        //log
        Log.d("deletePassword", password.toString());
    }
}
```

This is my RecyclerAdapter class

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<Password> myPasswords;
    public RecyclerAdapter(List<Password> myPasswords) {
        this.myPasswords = myPasswords;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_recycler_layout,parent,false));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Password myPass = getItem(position);
        holder.recImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        holder.recTitle.setText(myPass.getTitle());
        holder.recPassword.setText(myPass.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myPasswords.size();
    }

    public Password getItem(int position){
        return myPasswords.get(position);
    }


    //swipe to delete-dismiss
    public void dismissItem(int position){
        myPasswords.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        TextView recTitle,recPassword;
        ImageView recImage;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recTitle);
            recPassword = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recPassword);
            recImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recImage);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd just like to point out that SQLite and MySQL are completely different and MySQLite is not a thing.

Comment: I want to thank you @cricket_007 for the corrections in my question and for your answer.There are no errors in my code. You really saved me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my Database can't be called on RecyclerAdapter

Why can't you give the RecyclerAdapter the database object?

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<Password> myPasswords;
    MySQLiteHelper db;

    public RecyclerAdapter(MySQLiteHelper db) {
        this.db = db;
        this.myPasswords = db.getAllPasswords();
    }
```

Obviously, you have to determine if this approach has any potential side-effects for the rest of the code, but it just shows that it is possible to use the database inside of the RecyclerAdapter class

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your answer in the code itself, you basically do CRU (D)elete operation to solve your issue.

So from your swipe class, make this call:

```
<database variable>.deletePassword(the key you want to delete)
```

And yes do add the following notifyDataSetChange() so that screen refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

You execute detele  query in Recyclerview in adapter

```
    //swipe to delete-dismiss
public void dismissItem(int position){
    myPasswords.remove(position);
    Here you want excute the query
    ////deletePassword(Password password)(your query)

    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```